# Android gradle error after upgrade google-services to 4.3.2

Tags: android, firebase

After i change my android google-services from **4.2.0** to **4.3.2** i get this error when build:

Any help is appreciate.

```
Unable to load class 'com.google.android.gms.dependencies.DependencyAnalyzer'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:<ul><li>Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt 
(this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)</li><li>The state of a Gradle build 
process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)</li><li>Your project may be using a third-party 
plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle 
requested by the project.</li></ul>In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing 
the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Cause: com/google/android/gms/dependencies/DependencyAnalyzer
```

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio menu go to File ->Invalidate caches and restart

Answer (score 0):

Close your android studio and try to remove caches (if windows) from `C:\Users\username\.gradle\caches` and `C:\Users\username\.android\cache` and reimport your project.